# IIS URL rewrite conflict between files and urls

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have the below config for url rewrite in my IIS

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|csv|ttf|woff|woff2|pdf|mp4|mov|ics" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(php_scripts)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/documents/intranet_documents/" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

The negate directive is there to prevent rewrite for website assets files (css, fonts, etc.) as well as other files from the documents upload/download section.

The issue I just came across is this, one of the urls is like this http://intranet/HR/Training-Basics however when I try to navigate to this url I get 404 because it is being caught by the negate function for file extension ics.

So, I need to be able to access this url, but at the same time I need to be able to download the "ics" files. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the condition pattern from ics to\.ics, so that the rewrite rule will only rewrite based on file extension instead of specific string segment.

```
                                     <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|csv|ttf|woff|woff2|pdf|mp4|mov|ics)" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(php_scripts)" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/documents/intranet_documents/" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```